# Why won't my SQL data table code compile in Pycharm (compiles in python 3)

Tags: python, database, api, datatable, pycharm

```
import json
import urllib
import sqlite3

import temp

def loading():
    url = 'https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?page=1'  # URL for API 1-5json_obj = urllib.urlopen(url)
    response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = json.load(response)  # loads the url and set it into data variable

    for item in data[0].keys():
        print(item)
        return data  # Get the keys
# def loading():
# print " LOADING API(s)"
# urllib.urlopen('https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?page=1')
# temp = json.dumps(data[1])
# print (json.dumps(data[1]))
# print (" ")
def createDB(data):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('comp.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    # Create table
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comp
        (description text, title text, url text, company_logo text, company text, id integer primary key, company_url text, how_to_apply text,
        location text, type text, created_at timestamp)''')
    temp_values = list(tuple())
    for item in data:
        print (item)
        list_of_values = [v for k, v in item.items()]
        tuple_of_values = tuple(list_of_values)
        temp_values.append(tuple_of_values)
        c.executemany('INSERT INTO comp VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', temp_values)
        #TO DO
        # Make sub sets for each category call
        # put in category for each ? in table


def main():
    data = loading()
    createDB(data)

main()
```

This code takes a URL from GitHub Jobs and loads the data into a SQL data table into categories (title, location ect..) It runs in Python 3 terminal but cannot run in Pycharm which has me stumped.

Error messages:

> File "/Users/John/PycharmProjects/N/Sprint_2/Database.py", line 44, in main createDB(data) File "/Users/John/PycharmProjects/N/Sprint_2/Database.py", line 36, in createDB c.executemany('INSERT INTO comp VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', temp_values) sqlite3.IntegrityError: datatype mismatch

Comment: Did you get any error messages?

Comment: File "/Users/John/PycharmProjects/N/Sprint_2/Database.py", line 44, in main
    createDB(data)
  File "/Users/John/PycharmProjects/N/Sprint_2/Database.py", line 36, in createDB
    c.executemany('INSERT INTO comp VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', temp_values)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: datatype mismatch